# Why is Inception Net so bad for my model?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, loss-functions, artificial-intelligence

I am running Inception Encoder Net with Batch Normalisation on images of cell nuclei, in particular, there are thousands of data points to be classified into 5 groups. I have run various ResNet models and an Inception BN model and found that the ResNet models are all far superior and in fact, Inception gives quite frankly terrible results and I have one category in the training set which is unbalanced i.e. 5% of the dataset and Inception makes the DICE results for this one close to 0 in comparison to ResNet which has a score of 0.5.

Furthermore, the loss function barely gets minimised. Is there any reason that could be, does Inception not work well for small data points perhaps? I am sure I have implemented it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

(you should state your framework, model config, input and output to make guessing easier)

A few possibilities if you use pre-trained model and load weights,

1. image size: image size should close to 299 or 224 depends pre-trained model
2. image transformation: if Pytorch, additional transformation is required. e.g. transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
3. Inception is relative "Deep" network, try simpler networks, MobileNetV2, VGG16.

Comment: Yes the image size is 270x270, I have already normalised the images and also Residual Nets can be relatively deep such as ResNet101/152. I'm wondering if it's a technical problem of Inception that doesn't work as well as Residual networks

Comment: personal experience, for small image, MobileNet or RestNet34 work fine, medium size, ResNet34, 50, 101 could work, large image ResNet152 or EffNetB5 B6. If you want to try new things maybe visual transformer. why Inception?